# Duplicate code in day of the week event handlers

Tags: c#

```
  private static void OnSundayChangedCallBack(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        BinaryDataGrid c = sender as BinaryDataGrid;
        if (c != null)
        {

            if (_shouldCallBack)
            {
                if (c.Sunday.Length == 4)
                    return;
                Days day = (Days)c.dataGrid.Items[0];
                byte[] newArray = new byte[c.Sunday.Length + 1];
                newArray[0] = Convert.ToByte(0);
                c.Sunday.CopyTo(newArray, 1);
                day.Value = BitConverter.ToInt32(newArray.Reverse().ToArray(), 0);
                _sun = day.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                _shouldCallBack = true;
                c.Sunday = BitConverter.GetBytes(_sun).Reverse().ToArray().Skip(1).ToArray();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void OnMondayChangedCallBack(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        BinaryDataGrid c = sender as BinaryDataGrid;
        if (c != null)
        {
            if (_shouldCallBack)
            {
                if (c.Monday.Length == 4)
                    return;
                Days day = (Days)c.dataGrid.Items[1];
                byte[] newArray = new byte[c.Monday.Length + 1];
                newArray[0] = Convert.ToByte(0);
                c.Monday.CopyTo(newArray, 1);
                day.Value = BitConverter.ToInt32(newArray.Reverse().ToArray(), 0);
                _mon = day.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                _shouldCallBack = true;
                c.Monday = BitConverter.GetBytes(_mon).Reverse().ToArray().Skip(1).ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
```

I've got the same code for every week day, how can I generalize this so I don't have 6 duplicates of the code above?

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is:

1. Add a parameter of type `System.DayOfWeek` called, say, `day_of_week`.
2. Replace the fields `BinaryDataGrid.Sunday`, `.Monday`, etc. with a `Dictionary<K,V>` that has a key of type `System.DayOfWeek` and use `day_of_week` to access values within that dictionary.
3. Do the same for your `_sun`, `_mon` etc. global variables. (For which you will burn in hell, incidentally.)

If you cannot modify `BinaryDataGrid`, then write two helper methods, one for getting and one for setting the value of the day member of `BinaryDataGrid`: Each method has a `switch( day_of_week )` and modifies the appropriate member of `BinaryDataGrid`.

Good luck and have fun.

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestion, i'll definately improve that, but kindly enlighten me on 3rd point, (For which you will burn in hell, incidentally.) If this is that bad, guide me towards something that will help me fix that and also why this is so bad.

Comment: From wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable): "They are usually considered bad practice precisely because of their non-locality: a global variable can potentially be modified from anywhere (unless they reside in protected memory or are otherwise rendered read-only), and any part of the program may depend on it. A global variable therefore has an unlimited potential for creating mutual dependencies, and adding mutual dependencies increases complexity."

If you want to read more, here: "Global Variables are Bad" http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad

Comment: I do not know why you had to use them, and what you are trying to achieve with them, so I cannot help you get rid of them.

Comment: Actually i believe i could replace them with private properties, Thanks anyways

Comment: Thanks for the accept. In order to replace them with private properties you will first need to make your methods non-static, instead of static which they are now. And that will probably open up another can of worms. So if you can just get away by leaving them as they are, just swipe them under the carpet and move on.

Answer (score 1):

Mike Nakis has covered most of the design issues, so I'm going to cover some of the smaller points.

**Var**

Use the `var` keyword when defining method-scope variables for which the right hand side of the definition makes the type obvious. This saves you time when you come to refactor, and is neater.

e.g.

```
BinaryDataGrid c = sender as BinaryDataGrid;
```

should be

```
var c = sender as BinaryDataGrid;
```

**Naming**

Don't use single-character variable names. These do nothing but make the code more difficult to comprehend. Extra characters are free, so be descriptive.

```
var dateGrid = sender as BinaryDataGrid;
```

**Braces**

Always prefer to use braces for your if statements, it's cleaner, spaces things out better, and it's a StyleCop violation not to. Additionally, prefer to surround any statement involving braces with empty lines, this improves readability. Additionally, try to give your statements some space. Group together related statements, but leave a gap between unrelated ones.

So

```
if (_shouldCallBack)
{
    if (c.Sunday.Length == 4)
        return;
    Days day = (Days)c.dataGrid.Items[0];
    byte[] newArray = new byte[c.Sunday.Length + 1];
    newArray[0] = Convert.ToByte(0);
    c.Sunday.CopyTo(newArray, 1);
    day.Value = BitConverter.ToInt32(newArray.Reverse().ToArray(), 0);
    _sun = day.Value;
}
else
{
    _shouldCallBack = true;
    c.Sunday = BitConverter.GetBytes(_sun).Reverse().ToArray().Skip(1).ToArray();
}
```

Looks better as

```
if (_shouldCallBack)
{
    if (c.Sunday.Length == 4)
    {
        return;
    }

    Days day = (Days)c.dataGrid.Items[0];

    byte[] newArray = new byte[c.Sunday.Length + 1];
    newArray[0] = Convert.ToByte(0);

    c.Sunday.CopyTo(newArray, 1);

    day.Value = BitConverter.ToInt32(newArray.Reverse().ToArray(), 0);

    _sun = day.Value;
}
else
{
    _shouldCallBack = true;

    c.Sunday = BitConverter.GetBytes(_sun).Reverse().ToArray().Skip(1).ToArray();
}
```

**ToArray**

You have a duplicate call to ToArray that is wasted execution time here:

```
c.Sunday = BitConverter.GetBytes(_sun).Reverse().ToArray().Skip(1).ToArray();
```

Instead simply call:

```
c.Sunday = BitConverter.GetBytes(_sun).Reverse().Skip(1).ToArray();
```

**Design**

This is quite a lot of logic for what looks to be code-behind. I would recommend looking into some more well-structured patterns such as MVVM to keep your code separate from your view.